# Job Manager plugin help?

Tags: pages

I've installed the [Job Manager plugin](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/job-manager/) on my website.

I would like for the job listings to display on my jobs page, eg. `example.com/jobs/` instead of `example.com/jobs/jobs/`...

How can I go about this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

the plugin creates a page on activation named "Job Listing"

so go to settings >> reading >> Front page displays:

pick "A static page (select below)" and for "Front page: " select "Job Listing".